# combining django with ajax -- change a table entry without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-templates

Currently, I have a giant table that displays the query results. I display the background colors of my entries based on the "type" of the entry. I also added two links for the user to change the type of the entry, if they wish.

Very simple template code below. You can see that the user can change the type of the entry by visiting the `/changetype/` url. And after the type is changed, I redirect the user back to the original page, with a new type (and of course a different background color). User might also delete the entry

```
<table>
    {% for entry in entries %}
            {% if entry.type == 1 %}
                <tr bgcolor= '#007f7f'>
            {% elif entry.type == -1 %}
                <tr bgcolor= '#f5cbe1'>    
            {% endif %}
                <td width="90 pixels">{{ entry.field1 }}</td>  
                <td width="60 pixels">{{ entry.field2 }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/changetype/?pk={{entry.pk}}&newtype=1">newtype1</a>
                    <a href="/changetype?pk={{entry.pk}}&newtype=-1">newtype2</a>
                    <a href="/changetype?pk={{entry.pk}}&action=delete">delete</a>
                <td>
</table>
```

The annoying issue is, when the type is changed, the browser has to refresh the whole page to reflect the change of background color.

I want to combine this with ajax, so the change would be reflected without having the refresh the whole page.

I heard that dajax is one of the best frameworks of combining django and ajax. I wonder how this can be achieved in dajax? I have little experience in ajax (and I also think django is much easier to maintain than ajax), so I would like to write as little ajax as possible...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about dajax, but the following is an example of how to do this with jquery. You wouldn't need to change your django view (although you probably should). The ajax checks for an http 200 from the django view before making the changes to your table.

```
$('document').ready(function() { 
    $('td a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        var tableRow = $(this).parents('tr');
        var action = $(this).html();
        $.ajax({
            url: href,
            success: function() {
                  if (action == 'newtype1') {
                      tableRow.attr('bgcolor', '#007f7f');
                  } else if (action == 'newtype2') {
                      tableRow.attr('bgcolor', '#f5cbe1');
                  } else if (action == 'delete') {
                      tableRow.remove();
            },
        )};
    }
}
```

You would add this code to the `<head>` of your page.

1. The code waits for the page to be fully loaded (that's the `ready()` function).
2. It adds a click event to every anchor tag within a table cell (`$('td a').click()`).
3. The default action of the event is stopped (ie we don't follow the link and open a new page)
4. Then an ajax call is made to the href of the anchor tag.
5. When an http response with a 200 status code is received, the row is updated depending on the value of the text in the anchor (that's the `success:` callback)

Comment: Hi Aidan, thanks for your reply. But where should I put this function? I am a bit confused here, since this function doesn't try to find ONE tr to change bgcolor... so there should be some magic to associate each http 200 response to each tr. I could be completely wrong, again I am very new to ajax.

Comment: Thanks Aidan. Last question, if I only want one type of td (i.e., not all my tables are used for displaying entries) to be triggered with that click function, how should I change it?

Comment: Add a class to the td and select the anchors on the basis of the class - $('td.editable_row a').click() - jquery uses css selectors.